# Web Essentials causing IDE to hang every time I save

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

I'm using web essentials to pre-compile all of my less files, of which there are many.

I have the bootstrap source (30+ less files) and my own 8 less files.

Merely saving a small change stops visual studio for a good 30 seconds. I'm obviously making a lot of changes, so I'm wasting a lot of time.

**Is there any way of optimising this?**

I'm aware there are equivalent plug-ins (work bench) but you have to pay for the LESS compiler. I'll do this as I suppose it's worth it, but only as a last resort.

Comment: Are you making changes while running the project?

Comment: You could change it so it only compiles the LESS files on build rather than save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio : `Tools > Options...`
Then : `Web Essentials > LESS` 
and set `Compile files on save` to `False` so it won't compile every files each time you save a file.